# is there a sense of calling std::forward on this object in method call (as opposite to arguments)?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I wonder if `std::forward` has a sense here.

```
template <class T>
void juju(T && x) {
  std::forward<T>(x).jaja();
}
```

I guess it has no sense, because `this` is always a pointer in a method call, so there is no difference if it is made out of r-value or l-value reference. But please confirm my intuition or explain why I'm wrong.

Example above is a simplified [method from this code](https://github.com/oneapi-src/distributed-ranges/blob/main/include/dr/shp/algorithms/for_each.hpp#L27) with `juju` being `for_each`, `T` being `ExecutionPolicy` and `jaja` being `get_devices`.

Comment: A member function can have different overloads for lvalue and rvalue references.

Comment: @molbdnilo, this is it! I missed that there are such overloads possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You went too fast when you considered `this` inside the method. Before the member method is called there is overload resolution. And there can be different overloads for l-value and r-value references:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


template <class T>
void juju(T && x) {
  std::forward<T>(x).jaja();
}

struct foo {
    void jaja() & { std::cout << "hello\n";}
              //^
    void jaja() && { std::cout << "&&\n";}
              //^^
};

int main(){
    juju(foo{});
    foo f;
    juju(f);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/TPG17sdKf):

```
&&
hello
```